# How do I get a list of tables from MySQL using Java's DatabaseMetaData?

Tags: java, mysql

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
metadata.getTables(catalog, schemaPattern, tableNamePattern, types);
```

What fields are required to get a list of tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a list of all tables, you should use:

```
metadata.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
```

Comment: For clarity, table names will en up in `resultSet.getString(3)`